# Algorithm to construct curve bridging graph given points with location and velocity where time axis is constant

Tags: c#, algorithm, interpolation

I am recording the location and velocity of an object over time. I need to form a graph where the X axis is continuous (time) and the Y axis is one of the 3 dimensions of the object (X, Y, or Z). I will construct a graph for each of the 3 axes. When recording a point, I have its time and location/velocity. This is not a line of best fit; it needs to go through each point and most accurately as possible predict where the object was between samplings. I am trying to interpolate between the recorded points in a non-linear way.

I am not sure what this data type would look like to store the curve. Later I need to reverse this graph so I can play back the recording. I know graphs are equations, and I do need a function where I can input a value (time) and return a result (location).

So to restate my two-part question:

1. What data type should this graph be stored as?
2. What algorithm can I use provided time, location, and velocity?

I am using C#.

Comment: Do you have the velocity per dimension? Then I would go with a Hermite spline. If you don't, then this approach needs some further thoughts, but Hermite splines should be applicable, too.

Comment: When recording a point I can sample the current location of the object and its current velocity in each direction.

Comment: Then use a simple hermite interpolation. Wikipedia gives you the necessary formulae.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know both the position and the velocity of the object at each time point, the natural choice would be to use [cubic spline](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) interpolation.

Specifically, let the position and velocity vectors of the object at time *t*<sub>0</sub> be *x*<sub>0</sub> and *v*<sub>0</sub>, and let the corresponding position and velocity at time *t*<sub>1</sub> > *t*<sub>0</sub> be *x*<sub>1</sub> and *v*<sub>1</sub>.  Then there is a unique cubic polynomial:

*p*(*t*) = *at*<sup>3</sup> + *bt*<sup>2</sup> + *ct* + *d*

with derivative:

*p*'(*t*) = 3*at*<sup>2</sup> + 2**bt** + *c*

such that *p*(*t*<sub>0</sub>) = *x*<sub>0</sub>, *p*'(*t*<sub>0</sub>) = *v*<sub>0</sub>, *p*(*t*<sub>1</sub>) = *x*<sub>1</sub> and *p*'(*t*<sub>1</sub>) = *v*<sub>1</sub>.
We can use this polynomial to interpolate the position and velocity of the object at any time *t*<sub>0</sub> ≤ *t* ≤ *t*<sub>1</sub> by choosing *x*(*t*) = *p*(*t*) and *v*(*t*) = *p*'(*t*).

---

It's possible to solve for the coefficients *a*, *b*, *c*, *d* of *p* directly from the boundary conditions above, but in practice, it's easiest to start by shifting and rescaling time by *t* ↦ (*t* − *t*<sub>0</sub>) / (*t*<sub>1</sub> − *t*<sub>0</sub>), so that *t*<sub>0</sub> maps to 0 and *t*<sub>1</sub> maps to 1.  (Note that this also requires us to rescale the velocities to *v*<sub>0</sub>* = *v*<sub>0</sub> / (*t*<sub>1</sub> − *t*<sub>0</sub>) and *v*<sub>1</sub>* = *v*<sub>1</sub> / (*t*<sub>1</sub> − *t*<sub>0</sub>).)  This gives us the four equations:

*p*(0) = *d* = *x*<sub>0</sub>,
    *p*'(0) = *c* = *v*<sub>0</sub>*,
    *p*(1) = *a* + *b* + *c* + *d* = *x*<sub>1</sub>,
    *p*'(1) = 3*a* + 2*b* + *c* = *v*<sub>1</sub>*.

The first two equations directly give the coefficients *c* and *d*, so we only need to solve for *a* and *b*.  A little bit of linear algebra gives the solution:

*a* = *v*<sub>0</sub>* + *v*<sub>1</sub>* + 2(*x*<sub>0</sub> − x<sub>1</sub>),
    *b* = −2*v*<sub>0</sub>* − *v*<sub>1</sub>* − 3(*x*<sub>0</sub> − *x*<sub>1</sub>),
    *c* = *v*<sub>0</sub>*,
    *d* = *x*<sub>0</sub>.

We can then plug these values back into the definition of *p* above and evaluate it at *t** = (*t* − *t*<sub>0</sub>) / (*t*<sub>1</sub> − *t*<sub>0</sub>) to get the interpolated position of the object at time *t*.  To get the velocity, we can plug the same values into *p*', evaluate it at *t** and multiply the result by (*t*<sub>1</sub> − *t*<sub>0</sub>) to rescale it back into our proper time.

Since this is Stack Overflow, here's some simple Python code to do this:

```python
def interpolate (t, t0, x0, v0, t1, x1, v1):
    # scale time so that t0 -> 0 and t1 -> 1
    timescale = t1 - t0
    t = (t - t0) / timescale
    v0 /= timescale
    v1 /= timescale

    # calculate the coefficients of the polynomial
    a = v0 + v1 + 2*(x0 - x1)
    b = -2*v0 - v1 - 3*(x0 - x1)
    c = v0
    d = x0

    # calculate position and velocity at time t
    x = ((a*t + b)*t + c)*t + d
    v = ((3*a*t + 2*b)*t + c) * timescale
    return (x, v)
```

(Converting this to C# should be straightforward, since basic arithmetic works the same in both languages.)

Note that you can do the interpolation either in all three dimensions at once, by treating the positions and velocities (and the polynomial coefficients) as vectors, or you can simply do it in one dimension at a time; the interpolated positions and velocities depend linearly on the originals, so the result is the same either way (and doesn't depend on how you choose your coordinate axes).